# MIPS lw semantics: difference between "lw $t2, $t0" and "lw $t2, ($t0)"?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm picking up some MIPS in this [quick tutorial](http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm), where the author distinguishes between these two lw instructions: 
`lw $t2, $t0    # copy word (4 bytes) at source RAM location to destination register.`

`lw $t2, ($t0)    # load word at RAM address contained in $t0 into $t2`

I feel like the author's two comments mean the same...
When I think of these registers as loosely pointers in C++ (of course they're not since registers contain both memory addresses and actual data), both statements seem to do the same thing: copying $t0's "pointee" into $t2, so that $t2's actual value is $t0's "pointee", basically:

```
Word * $t0, $t2; //some hypothetical pointers
Word someData=1111000011110000.... //some hypothetical type (32 bits in total)
someData = *$t0; //de-reference $t0 and copy its value into someData
$t2 = someData; //impossible in real C++ but you know what I mean
```

Is there any difference between those two instructions at all? What about `lw $t2, 0($t0)` and `lw $t2, (0)$t0`? I'm so confused...

Comment: Where did you find `lw $t2, $t0`? It's not used on the page you linked to. Anyway, that's not a valid MIPS instruction.

Comment: I was reading this part: `lw register_destination, RAM_source
#copy word (4 bytes) at source RAM location to destination register.` So I guess the author didn't mean `lw register_destination, RAM_source` to be the exact format of the instruction then

Comment: `lw $t2, $t0` wouldn't match that pattern since `$t0` is a register, not a RAM_source.

Comment: So the dereferencing is necessary...$t0 points to a RAM_source, whereas [$t0] IS the RAM_source, is that correct?

Comment: Well, the registers can contain any 32-bit value. Whether or not those values are valid addresses or not isn't really relevant until you try to use the register as an address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lw $t2, $t0` isn't a MIPS instruction --- I suspect you may have misread the page.

In general, in assembler-land, `(thing)` or `[thing]` is the common convention for *value at address `thing`*. So `lw $t2, ($t0)` means *load the word at the address in `$t0`*. Yes, this is exactly how pointers work. It's the equivalent of, in C:

```
t2 = *(uint32_t*)t0;
```

It is also the same instruction as `lw $t2, 0($t0)`. The assembler just allows you to emit the number if it's 0; the number is an offset applied to `$t0`, so the address accessed is `$t0+1234`. `lw $t2, 1234($t0)` is:

```
t2 = *(uint32_t*)(t0 + 1234);
```

MIPS is very regular, unlike x86, and the only instructions that touch memory are the load and store instructions. You won't see this construction anywhere else.

Comment: I'm not very versed in C...could you please explain what `(uint32_t*)` does in your code? Does that simply indicate "whatever follows is of unsigned-integer-32-bit-pointer-type" ?